# Web Development program for Macs

Tags: c#, asp.net, macos, web-applications

I have a Mac running OSX 10.8 and my question is:

What is a good web development program that I can use to create applications in C# and ASP.Net? Or Somewhat similar  to Visual Studio.

Comment: I think your best bet is Windows on parallels and then just install Visual Studio there.

Comment: Check [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) and [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/). From [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784356/developing-with-c-sharp-on-osx-and-mono). Your question is a duplicate, however, and will be marked as such.

Answer (score 3):

I use Visual Studio on Windows and Xamarin on Mac.
Xamarin is suprisingly good :) Not Visual Studio, but they are getting there!

http://xamarin.com/